# How do I replace certain characters in a String without using .replace()?

Tags: java, string

I have to write a programme that encrypts and decrypts hidden messages. My problem is changing the alphabet. Originally I was going to use .replace() method, however, my teacher said we're not allowed to. The only methods we are allowed to do are,

```
.indexof();
.length();
.substring();
```

I have no idea how I'm supposed to do this. For example, Apple would be &**$# but how can I do this without .replace();

Comment: By ***writing*** your own version of `replace`. How does `replace` do it? **Hint 1**: `String`s are immutable, so you have to build a new `String` to alter anything. **Hint 2**: There is a class called `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `String.replace()` is limited, only three APIs is allowed. Apparently, `StringBuilder` is out of range.

Comment: This questions is too good to learn more about the String Class. You can start getting your `string` that you wanna replace and creating the `substring` using the `indexof`. Next... is with you! Good Lock! and... Enjoy it, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the idea, can be optimised by yourself :

```
public String replace(String original, String toBeReplacedStr, String withStr) {
    while(true) {
      int i = original.indexOf(toBeReplacedStr);
      if (i == -1) {
         break;
      }
      original = original.substring(0, i) + withStr + original.substring(i + toBeReplacedStr.length());
    }
    return original;
}
```

Or can use the `StringBuilder` with recursion:

```
public String replace(String original, String toBeReplacedStr, String withStr) {
    int i = original.indexOf(toBeReplacedStr);
    if (i < 0) {
      return original;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String before = original.substring(0, i);

    String rawAfter  = original.substring(i + toBeReplacedStr.length());
    String replacedAfter = replace(rawAfter, toBeReplacedStr, withStr);
    return sb.append(before).append(withStr).append(replacedAfter).toString();
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use `StringBuilder` here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks, but there is no `split()` method in the requirement. would be complicated to use StringBuilder here?

Comment: No, it would be _easy_ and efficient to use string builder.  Instead of concatenating strings, you can use `append()`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just came up with a version using `StringBuilder` and recursion. can add your complements if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read source code of `String.replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` to implement your own method.

```
public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar) {
        if (oldChar != newChar) {
            int len = value.length;
            int i = -1;
            char[] val = value; /* avoid getfield opcode */

            while (++i < len) {
                if (val[i] == oldChar) { // comment 1, aims to find 
          // first index of oldChar. You can use indexOf() to achieve this.
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i < len) {
                char buf[] = new char[len];
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    buf[j] = val[j]; // comment 2, copy prefix chars 
          // before the oldChar to buf. You can use subString() to achieve this.
                }
                while (i < len) {
                    char c = val[i];
                    buf[i] = (c == oldChar) ? newChar : c; // comment 3, 
        // replace oldChar with newChar, for other chars, just copy. 
        // You can use the thought above. I suggest you divide to 3 
        // methods to do "replace" thing.
                    i++;
                }
                return new String(buf, true);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```